# Easy statistics question with an (not so) easy answer

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

Im working on a Kaggle machine learning proyect (https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) and my target variable is "SalePrice" of a particular house.

After plotting the data I can see that my  [target variable doesnt show a normal distribution and have positive skewness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Kpb.png)

So I (kind of) normalize it by [taking the log of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwqo7.png)

When I run my predictions using my regressors later, am I going to predict the log of the sale price? In this case, what should I do?

Is it okay just to do the inverse transformation or is it mathematical or statisticaly wrong?

Comment: You are going to predict whatever you feed; if you feed logarithms, you are going to predict logarithms. That said, please keep in mind that SO is about *specific coding* questions and not a tutorial service.

Comment: Taking logarithms to make a variable more nearly normal is A-OK and something that's widely done for that purpose. One way to look at it is that it's converting multiplicative noise to additive noise. Do you find that small prices have small variance, and large prices have large variance? If so then multiplicative noise is a reasonable model. Btw discussions questions such as this are considered off topic for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes your model will predict the log of the house price, and there's nothing wrong with taking the exponential of that (mathematically speaking) to get back to the actual house price.

Forgetting statistics for a moment, if you have taken the log of your house price for your training data, your algorithm doesn't "know" that, it's just a different set of numbers, and your regressor is going to just fit to a different curve.

One practical problem is, when you take the exponential of your output, you better be quite confident in the precision of the predicted number. A small difference in your log-predicted-house prices, after being exponentiated, could make a large difference in your output. Is your model going to be able to achieve that level of precision?